# MVC - repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I learn MVC and Repository Pattern, and don't clear how to reach data.
(I used asp.net with DAL, where call stored procedure and return dataview or dataset) 
I would like to use jqgrid (datasource JSON).

- should I use entity framework recommended only ONE table operations
  or should I use Entity Framework to get data for complex type?
  (most of the grid has multiple table join result set return by a stored procedure)
- when I use generic repository with GetAll, FindBy, Add, Delete, Update method, but I need only GetAll method, the best way to create another generic repository with GetAll method, and use that?
- if i want to use stored procedure with multiple result set, which is the best way to reach it? (Entity Framework complex datatype handle only one result set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is rather broad, however here are some points to help out:

1. Use EF for most simple stuff (load a few records, update one/two records), but use stored procedures when you have to code business logic tightly connected to data (better performance).
2. Use views for grids when possible and procedures if you have to. If views are based on large tables, apply filters before issuing a query to reduce query execution times, and if possible disable sorting on joined columns.
3. If multiple result sets are really important to you, then you have to code it yourself either with ADO.NET or use some lightweight ORM (such as Dapper) on top of the entities generated by EF. Using EF assumes that you will forgo some functionalities of ADP.NET (such as multiple result sets and table value parameters).

Comment: In this case I will create:
- DAL class libary project to reach data with ado.net
- MVC projekt with Repository, and with model using entity framework for simple operations, and controller calls through repo DAL or entity framework methods. For validation I use jquery.validation instead of service layer, or model validation
This is a correct architecture?

Comment: DAL - is where you should put the EF models and repositories. Create a service layer library and put your business logic. MVC should reference DAL and service layer. Data format validation you can do with jquery or in the controller. However, business logic validation should be done in the service layer.